# minimal image editor component

Tags: jakarta-ee, components

I am looking for a web component which i can  embed in my j2ee application.

The only thing i need in the component is to be able to take a highligher and highlight certain areas in image. That's it.

any advise please? those i found are mostly doing advance stuff like scaling, flipping etc which i dont need. None of the component i found with this paint brush like capability where i can chose a color and draw a line on any part of image

i looked at other threads like on stackoverflow but none if for this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind i solved it using java.awt  applet features.